# Static member 'Case Insensitive Search' cannot be used on instance of type 'NSStringCompareOptions'

Tags: swift

In my code I have the error like CaseInsensitiveSearch in NsStringCompareOption but I don't to how to solve please help me for solve the issue, I post my code what i am tried.

```
var message = QBChatMessage()
let img_range = (message.text as NSString).rangeOfString("{{", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) ---> Error in this line.
```

Comment: Remove the `as NSString` ...

Comment: Removing the `as NSString` will not solve the problem.

Comment: @ScottThompson: You are right, that makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to be misleading, and the actual problem 
is that `message.text` is an *optional* string. In that case you can
use optional chaining:

```
if let img_range = message.text?.rangeOfString("{{", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
    print(img_range)
} else {
    // message.text is `nil` or does not contain the search string
}
```